# How do i fix "id attribute is not unique" in wordpress site (checking on achecker for wcag2.0)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, accessibility, wcag2.0

I am trying to make a wordpress website wcag 2 compatible. I am running the test on achecker and getting the error that matchHeight-js is not unique. How can I determine and fix the problem? I am viewing the page source and i can see the 2 id's that are the same but don't know what to do with them. Here is the [website link](http://zk-constructions.eu/) Here is the error I'm getting [achecker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAMIG.png) and here is the part of my code that is wrong [faulty page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMQkf.png). Can someone please help me fix this problem?

Comment: All IDs must be unique. So the solution would be to remove the ID on all but one element

Comment: I do not know how to pinpoint the element and remove the id. I am just starting with website development with wordpress, so I have very little coding knowledge.

Comment: The tool should be telling you what the element with the duplicate ID is

Comment: You are including the exact same script twice but from different file paths. So if you fix that (it is hard to tell you how as we do not know whether that is included in the head, programatically etc so you will have to research it) you will automatically fix the ID problem as only one script with the ID will be loaded. Ironically this is not actually an accessibility error, it is a false positive so from an accessibility perspective you can ignore it (as `<script>` tags are not accessed by screen readers it does not matter that they have duplicated IDs). **You can ignore the error for A11y**

Comment: But you should still fix it for other reasons obviously.

Comment: I can find the error if I view the page source in google chrome but I do not know how to identify the element in wordpress. These are the two lines:

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://zk-constructions.eu/wp-content/plugins/primary-addon-for-elementor/assets/js/jquery.matchHeight.min.js?ver=0.7.2' id='matchheight-js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://zk-constructions.eu/wp-content/themes/bizberg/assets/js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js?ver=0.7' id='matchHeight-js'></script>
I don't know what or where i can find and fix them in wordpress

Comment: Your problem is a plugin loading the same (nearly the same) library as your WP theme. I've put the start of some info into an answer as it was getting too long for a comment.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a bit more than just two elements happening to have the same id.

It looks as though two parts of your system are loading the same jquery library, albeit with slightly different versions.

The first is the plugin primary-addon-for-elementor and the second is your site's theme, bizberg. One or other of them should have checked to see whether the library assets they needed were already loaded.

Do you have access to a test site and/or the plugins or themes directory or can you inspect your theme's files in the WP backend as administrator under Appearance>Edit theme [I don't advise doing this on a live site!]. It may be simply a case of removing one of the calls (the <script lines that load the library) so they don't get called twice.

Any info you can give on what access you have to the system would be helpful and we may be able to pinpoint the problem more directly.

Comment: I have full access to the hosting provider and wordpress backend, this is a site that I am developing. I just tried deactivating primary add-on for elementor but the problem still persists.